# How to change a non top 3 values columns in a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that was made out of BOW results called df_BOW

dataframe looks like this

```
df_BOW
Out[42]: 
             blue      drama     this  ...      book      mask
0            3         0         1  ...         1         0
1            0         1         0  ...         0         4
2            0         1         3  ...         6         0
3            6         0         0  ...         1         0
4            7         2         0  ...         0         0
       ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...    ...
81991         0         0         0  ...         0         1
81992         0         0         0  ...         0         1
81993         3         3         5  ...         4         1
81994         4         0         0  ...         0         0
81995         0         1         0  ...         9         2
```

this data frame has around 12,000 column and 82,000 rows

I want to reduce the number of columns by doing this

for each row keep only top 3 columns and make everything else 0

so for row number 543 ( the original record looks like this)

```
             blue      drama     this  ...      book      mask
543          1         11        21  ...         7        4
```

It should become like this

```
             blue      drama     this  ...      book      mask
543          0         11        21  ...         7        0
```

only top 3 columns kept (drama, this, book) all other columns became zeros

```
             blue      drama     this  ...      book      mask
929          5         3         2     ...         4        3
```

will become

```
             blue      drama     this  ...      book      mask
929          5         3         0     ...         4        0
```

at the end of I should remove all columns that are zeros for all rows

I start putting this function to loop all rows and all columns

```
for  i in range(0, len(df_BOW.index)):
    Col1No = 0
    Col1Val = 0
    Col2No = 0
    Col2Val = 0
    Col3No = 0
    Col3Val = 0
    

    for j in range(0, len(df_BOW.columns)):
        if (df_BOW.iloc[i,j] > min(Col1Val, Col2Val, Col3Val)):
            if (Col1Val <= Col2Val) & (Col1Val <= Col3Val):
                df_BOW.iloc[i,Col1No] = 0
                Col1Val = df_BOW.iloc[i,j]
                Col1No = j
            elif (Col2Val <= Col1Val) & (Col2Val <= Col3Val):
                df_BOW.iloc[i,Col2No] = 0
                Col2Val = df_BOW.iloc[i,j]
                Col2No = j
            elif (Col3Val <= Col1Val) & (Col3Val <= Col2Val):
                df_BOW.iloc[i,Col3No] = 0
                Col3Val = df_BOW.iloc[i,j]
                Col3No = j
```

I don't think this loop is the best way to do that.

beside it will become impossible to do for top 50 columns with this loop.

is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html), pass keep as `first` to include the first record only if multiple value exists for top 3 largest values. Finally use `fillna(0)` to fill all the `NaN` columns with 0

```py
df.apply(lambda row: row.nlargest(3, keep='first'), axis=1).fillna(0)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
   blue  book  drama  mask  this
0   0.0   1.0    0.0   0.0   1.0
1   1.0   0.0    1.0   4.0   0.0
2   2.0   6.0    0.0   0.0   3.0
3   3.0   1.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
4   4.0   0.0    2.0   0.0   0.0
5   0.0   0.0    0.0   1.0   0.0
6   0.0   0.0    0.0   1.0   0.0
7   3.0   4.0    0.0   0.0   5.0
8   4.0   0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
9   0.0   9.0    1.0   2.0   0.0
```